# How to Redirect direct access to a subdomain and allowed only through a specific url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, webserver, subdomain

How to Redirect direct access to a subdomain and allowed only through a specific url

for example i have mydomain and sub.mydomain i want to Redirect direct access to sub.mydomain to mydomain and if someone access through sub.mydomain/url should be allowed !
i hope you guys understand what i'm trying to say.
Thanks
I TRIED

```
//code
$_SESSION['fromMain'] = "true";
header("Location: noaccess.php");
if($_SESSION['fromMain'] == "false"){
   //send them back
   header("Location: foo.php");
}
else{
   //reset the variable
   $_SESSION['fromMain'] = "false";
}
```

i triedd this too

```html
RewriteEngine On

# Allow access only from a specific directory on the specific URL
SetEnvIf Referer "http://specificurl\.com/specificdirectory" ref_allowed
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=ref_allowed

# Redirect to main domain for non-specific URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maindomain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://maindomain.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: From your description, it doesn't appear to be "direct access" you want to block (or redirect), but _any_ access to the subdomain's root? Or perhaps access to any URL _except_ `/url`? To what URL should the user be redirected to at `mydomain`? Without more context, the PHP code you have "tried" (although you've stated "i didn't try anything yet"?) doesn't make much sense - what is `$_SESSION['fromMain']`?

Comment: thanks you for reaching out! so let me explain , i have domain.com thats my main domain and i have sub.domain.com thats my subdomain , so i want my subdomain to be accedes only through a specif url example : sub.domain.com/folder/ and if some one tries to access my subdomain directly without the specific url i mentioned   he should be redirect to the main domain.com. so only people have the unique url for my subdomain to be allowed to get in.

Comment: i tried this one :
RewriteEngine On

# Allow access only from a specific directory on the specific URL
SetEnvIf Referer "http://specificurl\.com/specificdirectory" ref_allowed
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=ref_allowed

# Redirect to main domain for non-specific URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maindomain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://maindomain.com [L,R=301]
 
Still not working

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file? What kind of site is this? Static HTML? Do you have a front-controller pattern (like WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, Laravel, etc.)?

Comment: No thtas the only things i have on my subdomain .htaccess , i have a static HTML website

Answer (score 0):

> i want my subdomain to be accedes only through a specif url example : sub.domain.com/folder/ and if some one tries to access my subdomain directly without the specific url i mentioned he should be redirect to the main domain.com. so only people have the unique url for my subdomain to be allowed to get in.

It sounds like you just need to do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of the root `.htaccess` file in directory that the subdomain points to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com
RewriteRule !^url$ https://example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Where `url` is the specific URL that can be accessed via the subdomain. All other URLs are redirected. If this is a physical directory (you give `/folder/` as a secondary example) then the first *condition* (that checks the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var) is not required.

The first *condition* that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is only required if you have a front-controller pattern that rewrites requests (eg. WordPress, Joomla, Laravel, etc.)

But note that any assets (images, CSS, JS, etc.) that might reference the subdomain will also be blocked/redirected.

---

The PHP code you've posted doesn't really make sense. As written, it unconditionally redirects everything to `noaccess.php`? (But what is `$_SESSION['fromMain']`.

And the `.htaccess` code you've posted are two different methods for blocking referred links, which does not appear to be what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what actually work for me :

```
# Redirect index access to main domain
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect sub.example.org to example.org
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.org/ [L,R=301]

# Allow access to /me/ folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/me/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This is basically the same as what I posted in my answer. Although in your question you stated a "specific URL", but here you are allowing an entire filesystem directory (many URLs). However, your first rule is not required (requests to the root are already handled by the second rule). `RewriteBase` is not doing anything here. And the _condition_ (`RewriteCond` directive) in the second rule is not required (this should be handled by the `RewriteRule` directive instead - as in my answer). So, what you have here could be reduced to a one-liner: `RewriteRule !^me/ http://example.org/ [R=301,L]`.